# Wifi disconnects instantly

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, internet, wpa-supplicant

Hi I installed qubes on the x220 I bought on Ebay. 
Now I got the problem that wifi is not connecting. 
Qubes uses the sys-net VM to for internet connection based on fedora 29. It uses networkmanager for the connections though wpa_supplicant is installed as well. 
Ethernet works fine with LAN-cable but the issue is that wifi does not connect or disconnects instantly. The Adapter is Centrino Advanced-N 6205.
I am able to connect to the wifi using wpa_supplicant + dhclient as explained here https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/ubuntu-server-16-04-wifi-wpa-supplicant

The other qubes cannot use this connection however and I also do not want to use wpa_supplicant but rather NetworkManager. Maybe someone here can help me figure out what is causing NetworkManager refusing to stay connected.
I have tried following this suggestion changing the DHCPlient to dhclient https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/networking-connects-then-disconnects-with-14-2-ar9285-4175583671/ and here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager. 
But however that did not help as well. I don't know if it is because of the qubes environment so the settings differ.
I have also put IPv6 settings to ignore and connect only via IPv4 - did not help as well as the other way around.
I am able to connect to the wifi when I am "disabling" IPv4 and also putting IPv6 to "ignore" in the networkmanager-settings but however the CPU is used very much and obviously I do not have a working internet connection.

That's part of the output of dmesg:

```
[    5.542197] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls7: link is not ready
[    7.941038] fuse init (API version 7.26)
[    8.794429] iwlwifi 0000:00:07.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[    9.097792] iwlwifi 0000:00:07.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[    9.184467] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls7: link is not ready
[   12.437164] wls7: authenticate with 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:3a
[   12.449079] wls7: send auth to 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:3a (try 1/3)
[   12.521838] wls7: authenticated
[   12.523237] wls7: associate with 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:3a (try 1/3)
[   12.524847] wls7: RX AssocResp from 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:3a (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[   12.549671] wls7: associated
[   12.623230] wls7: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:3a
[   12.659060] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wls7: link becomes ready
[   12.660467] wls7: deauthenticating from 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:3a by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[   12.743637] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls7: link is not ready
[   12.844874] wls7: authenticate with 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:38
[   12.857316] wls7: send auth to 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:38 (try 1/3)
[   12.871455] wls7: authenticated
[   12.872100] wls7: associate with 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:38 (try 1/3)
[   12.875869] wls7: RX AssocResp from 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:38 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   12.905062] wls7: associated
[   12.920569] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wls7: link becomes ready
[   12.922015] wls7: deauthenticating from 94:4a:0c:a2:c4:38 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The remedy apparently was to update the fedora template. 
But maybe someone searching to that needs to change /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf to
`[main] dhcp=dhclient`
as described here:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/networking-connects-then-disconnects-with-14-2-ar9285-4175583671/
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager